# How to get value stored inside parent element

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework

I am pretty new to javascript and typescript type stuff. I am working on an ionic application that reads a list of values from a database. It then stores them in an array and loops through each element creating an ion-item. For each item, a delete button is created. I am wanting to make it so that when the user clicks on the delete button it will remove the value stored in the ion-item from the array. once the value is removed from the array I can update the database.

I initially tried using the iterable value used to generate the ion-item, but that doesn't make sense because it's no longer in scope. I am kind of lost on how to pass the value of an element where a button is located to a function.

```
        <ion-list class = "list" *ngIf="isCommentToggle" >
          <ion-item id = "comments" *ngFor="let item of streamComments">
            {{item}}
            <button *ngIf="item" color="danger" ion-button (click)="onDeleteComment()" {{item}}="deleteComment">Delete</button>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

**typescrip DOCUMENT with function**

```
  onDeleteComment(){

    this.gaugeList.addCommentList(this.stream);
  }
```

I am just wanting a way to capture the variable stored in the parent element from where the button is called[Here is the application view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR6Lx.png)

Comment: By 'iterable value used to generate the ion-item',  are you referring to `item`?

Answer (score 0):

**Try following process :**

```html
<ion-list class = "list" *ngIf="isCommentToggle" >
    <ion-item id = "comments" *ngFor="let item of streamComments;let i=index">
        {{item}}
        <button *ngIf="item" color="danger" ion-button (click)="onDeleteComment(i)" {{item}}="deleteComment">Delete</button>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Note that I have added `let i=index` in which `i` is index of each element. Now you can use that `i` to delete specific value from array something like below :

```js
onDeleteComment(i:number){
    this.streamComments.splice(i,1);
}
```

It's remove the one value from the `streamComments` array of index number `i`.

Hope it will help you !!!

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Hello mate just remove the item from the array and then sent the array back to db.

```
     <ion-list class = "list" *ngIf="isCommentToggle" >
      <ion-item id = "comments" *ngFor="let item of streamComments">
        {{item}}
        <button *ngIf="item" color="danger" ion-button 
         (click)="onDeleteComment(item)" 
         {{item}}="deleteComment">Delete</button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

And in your Ts

```
  onDeleteComment(item){
    let targetIndex = this.gaugeList.findIndex(element => element === item);
    this.gaugeList.splice(targetIndex, 1);
    //Now send this.gaugeList to backend
  }
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple! I wasn't sure if the variable used for the iterable would still hold a value since the ngFor loop had already been processed. I was trying to make that work by passing the value in {{item}} to the deleteComment variable. From there I would find the key index stored in it and delete it from the array.

This solution worked much better, however. 

By the way the .findIndex method wasn't working. It was telling me that the function was not defined in the provider, so i opted to use .indexOf instead.

Comment: I apologise for the blunder mate @scubasteve7 findIndex only works with a call back. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element into the `onDeleteComment()` function:

```
<button *ngIf="item" color="danger" ion-button (click)="onDeleteComment(item)"
    {{item}}="deleteComment">Delete</button>
```

Then in your Typescript:

```
onDeleteComment(item) {
    // Do whatever you need to do with 'item'
    this.gaugeList.addCommentList(this.stream);
}
```

Alternatively, you can also declare an index variable on your loop with `*ngFor="let item of streamComments; let i = index"` and pass that into `onDeleteComment()`. Then:

```
onDeleteComment(index: number) {
    // The item that called this function is this.streamComments[index]
    this.gaugeList.addCommentList(this.stream);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!